# Why does recursion work even if there's no base case?

Tags: c, recursion

I'm learning recursion , so i'm trying to create a program that reverse a number in array recursively and using divide and conquer technique (i'm not sure this is divide and conquer or not), so what my problem is, i want to know why if i delete line 11 the program still work properly, but if i delete line 16, it will goes infinitely.
And i checked through my debugger, i know why it's infinite loop, because each stacked frames index left is still less than right, this makes the loop goes infinitely, so my question, why recursive call start from check the while condition and skip the line 11? this is weird for me because i just learn some basics of recursive, so this is abit confusing for me. so in my code, the line 16 is considered as the base case? because i learn from tutorial that recursive need a base case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 10
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp= *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = temp;
}
void revcur (int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    if (left>=right) return; //This program still works even if i delete this line or comment 
    while (left<right)
    {
        swap(&arr[left],&arr[right]);
        revcur(arr,left+1,right-1);
        return; //This program will go to infinite recursive if i delete this
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[size]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    revcur(arr,0,size-1);
    int i; for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: We do not have line number in SO messages.

Comment: Inside the while loop `while (left<right)` you are incrementing and decrementing the variables left and right but the new values are not getting assigned.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose left=2 and right=1. What happens if you leave line 11 in, the condition will be true, and you will exit the function (return) immediately. When you remove line 11, you will get to the while loop. The while statement checks if left is less than right, which it is not. Therefore, it will skip all the code inside the while loop which brings you to the end of the function, and hence it will return automatically. This is identical behaviour to the case where you leave line 11 in place.

The reason it loops infinitely when you remove line 16 is because you are not updating "left" and "right" to a new value. So if left is indeed less than right, it will enter the loop and since the value of left and right never change, the next time it gets to the line with the "while" statement, "left" will still be less than "right" and hence the loop will continue indefinitely.

Comment: I got it, one more thing i wanna ask, why everytime the program enter the recursion, it check to the "while" statement, skipping the "if" statement? the recursion didn't start the loop from the beginning of the function? correct me if my statement above is wrong

Comment: Simply because the values of `left` and `right` are not getting updated.
Are you familiar with reentrant code and reentrancy?

Answer (score 2):

This code pattern:

```
while (condition)
{
    // do something
    return;
}
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
if (condition)
{
    // do something
    return;
}
```

In other words, your base case is `!condition`.

---

You could replace your implementation with

```
void revcur(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    if (left>=right) return;

    swap(&arr[left],&arr[right]);
    revcur(arr,left+1,right-1);
}
```

and that would be exactly equivalent (the `while` was never actually looping).

---

Your version seems to have vestiges of the iterative equivalent:

```
void revcur(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    while (left<right) {
        swap(&arr[left++],&arr[right--]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is overly complicated, actually it is simply doing this:

```
void revcur(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
  if (left<right)
  {
    swap(&arr[left], &arr[right]);
    revcur(arr, left + 1, right - 1);
  }
}
```

The `while` loop in your original function never loops more than once, so having 
`while` is actually pointless; it's just a weird way to write `if`.

Consider following functions.

```
void foo(int x)
{
  printf("x = %d\n",x );

  if (x > 0)
    foo(x - 1);
}


void bar(int x)
{
  printf("x = %d\n", x);

  while (x > 0)
  {
    bar(x - 1);
    return;
  }
}
```

`foo` and `bar` do exactly the same thing, except that `bar` is abusing the `while` loop using it as an `if` just like you did in your function.

Now try to remove the `return` from the `bar` function and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Well your function is a `void`. So the last time you call it in your recursion. It won't enter the while loop and so it won't call the function again, therefore ending the recursion. And because ypu have a return in your while loop I guess you could just replace it by an `if` statement and it would basicaly do the same and you could get rid of the `return`.

Comment: Why does it goes infinite loop if i remove `return;` under the recursion?

Comment: Because it never ends the condition of the while.

Comment: What does the fact that the function is void have to do with whether or not it enters the while loop?

Comment: Try replacing your statement `while (left<right)` with `if(left<right)` and get rid of the `return`. You should not have any infinite loop after that. Teh reason is in the while loop the function will enter till `left<right` with recursion. On the last call it wont enter the function but still be in the first while loop and without any return it wont left the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
if (left>=right) return; //This program still works even if i delete this line or comment
```

is just redundant.

If `left >= right` is true then the condition of the while statement `left < right`is false and the while loop will not be executed.

So you may remove the if statement.

```
void revcur (int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    while (left<right)
    {
        swap(&arr[left],&arr[right]);
        revcur(arr,left+1,right-1);
        return; //This program will go to infinite recursive if i delete this
    }
}
```

However you may not remove the return statement because in this case the loop will be infinite due to the fact that inside the loop the values of the variables `left` and `right` themselves are not changed and the condition of the while statement will always evaluate to true if it is initially evaluates to true.

On the other hand there is no sense to use the while statement because in any case it is assumed that the body of the loop will be executed only once due to the return statement. It is the condition of the while statement that is important.

So you may substitute the while statement for an if statement.

For example

```
void revcur (int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    if ( left < right)
    {
        swap(&arr[left],&arr[right]);
        revcur(arr,left+1,right-1);
    }
}
```

Take into account that if the array contains only one element then it will be swapped with itself that is the function will be have one more redundant recursive call.

The function can be rewritten as having only two parameters and without the redundant recursive call of itself.

Below is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written with two parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap( int *a, int *b )
{
    int temp= *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = temp;
}

void reverse( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        swap( &a[0], &a[n-1] );
        reverse( a + 1, n - 2 );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    reverse( a, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: How it works? That's interesting recursion for me. I couldn't figure it out, why it works even if `n-2` i mean, when the right index becomes 8 6 4 2 0, how could the swapping doesn't skip some index?

Comment: @owenizedd The function at first check whether the array has at least two elements. If for example the array has only one element then there are nothing to swap. If there are more than or equal to 2 elements then the first and the last elements are swapped that is 2 elements were swapped and the function called for the array with the elements without these two elements.